# Why does useContext accept a context object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the `SearchContext` context object defined in one component and I want it to be consumed by a component in a different file. Yet when I use `useContext(SearchContext)` in either the `MajorStatus` or `ClassType` component, Javascript throws a ReferenceError because `SearchContext` is not defined.

I was wondering why `useContext` needs a context object at all. According to the documentation, `useContext()`

> Accepts a context object (the value returned from React.createContext) and returns the current context value for that context. The current context value is determined by the value prop of the nearest <MyContext.Provider> above the calling component in the tree.

If the context value is determined by the value prop of the nearest provider, isn't it redundant to supply the context object? Is it necessary to not supply an argument to `useContext()` if the context object is in a different file? Thanks.

The parent component supplying context:

```js
  const SearchContext = React.createContext(onChangeHandler);

  return (
    <SearchContext.Provider value={ onChangeHandler }>
      <form className={styles.userInfo} method="post">
        <MajorStatus />
        <ClassType />
        <button
          type="submit"
          name="submitUserInfo"
          className={styles.submitUserInfoButton}
        >
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Child component:

```js
import { useContext } from "react";

function ClassType() {
  let { onChangeHandler } = useContext(SearchContext);

  return (
    <div className={styles.classType}>
      <span>Give me a</span>
      <Select
        className={styles.select}
        options={GEN_ED_CLASSES}
        onChange = {onChangeHandler}
      />
      <span>class</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ClassType;
```

Comment: You need to pass the context object so that `useContext` knows which context to get the value from, there could be multiple context providers up the stack

Comment: The documentation states "The current context value is determined by the value prop of the nearest <MyContext.Provider> above the calling component in the tree."

Comment: Where `MyContext` is the context object passed to `useContext`, not just the first context provider found. In your case the nearest `<SearchContext.Provider>`

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Does both the provider and consumer have to be in the same file then (so the context object passed to `useContext` is defined)?

Comment: No, you can import the context object into whatever file you need. If you get issues with circular imports then you might look into moving the context to a completely separate file from where you have the provider